# CSS positioning / Safari

Tags: css

I normally have issues with IE, but IE has played nice this time...

I have looked at my code over and over, and Google'd the issues, but i have not been able to fix it...

Can you have a look at
[RCN e-Cycle](http://dev.webwork.net.nz/e-cycle/)

The map on the left hand side renders correctly, i mean the place names using CSS positioning.

I am also using the same code to output a standalone map for embedding on other websites, this displays corrctly - 
[Standalone map](http://dev.webwork.net.nz/e-cycle/map/)

but, when i use the same code on another page with in my site, the positioning is all off...

And, further to that.
I have tested it in FF10, Safari 5.01 IE9 and Chrome 17 on my Win7 box
All play nice.

however, i saw it today on an OSX 10.6 box in Safari, and the positioning was off.
it was positioned the same as my incorrect page - dev.webwork.net.nz/e-cycle/locations/

I feel it must me a simple error if my incorrect page and Safari in OSX display it the same, but all be it incorrect.

Could someone have a look and see if they can point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: are you getting width() or height() values in JS that are used for positioning?  ive had a similar problem in the past with safari and had to explicitly declare CSS line-height:16px;

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you are positioning your labels `relative`, and then providing them a top and left. This tells the browser to offset each label from where it would normally appear in the flow, and this value may vary by browser. If you use absolute positioning, it takes the elements out of the flow completely and lets you tell the browser where to place them relative to a top-left origin.

I would recommend instead that you:
(1) position your `ul` holding all your labels "`position: relative`". Do this so that:
(2) position individual labels "`position: absolute`". You'll then need to adjust your top/left values for each label, but then you should get consistent, predictable behavior.

Good luck!